# Mysqli query not running - why not?

Tags: php, mysqli

In my document I recive and $_GET, this array I handle and build my query.
Then I try to run it. I get a blank page.

```html
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
  
  $skip = 0;
  foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
  {
   if($skip++ > 1) {
       if(!empty($value))
       {
        $link = new mysqli('IP-NUMBER', 'LOGIN', 'PASSWORD', 'DATABASE');

           $values = explode("_", $key);
        $insert_query = "INSERT INTO texts (language, parent_id, text) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        
        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($insert_query)){
         $stmt->bind_param("sis", $values[0], $values[1], $value);
         $stmt->execute();
         $stmt->close();
        }

       }
   }
  }
 }
```

```html
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
  
  $skip = 0;
  foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
  {
   if($skip++ > 1) {
       if(!empty($value))
       {
        $link = new mysqli('IP-NUMBER', 'LOGIN', 'PASSWORD', 'DATABASE');
        
           $values = explode("_", $key);
        $insert_query = "INSERT INTO texts (language, parent_id, text) VALUES ('".$values[0]."', ".$values[1].", '".$value."')";
        
        if ($result = $mysqli->query($insert_query)) {
         echo "Yes!";
        }

       }
   }
  }
 }
```

None of the above work, both produce an blank page.
And yes $value[1] is an int.

What easy noob mistake am I making here?

Comment: why this: `if($skip++ > 1)` you might want to use only `if($skip >= 1)` and at the end of the foreach loop add `$skip++`

Comment: Are you sure you got something in `$_GET['submit']`? Try `var_dump($_GET);` before your first `if` just to make sure how exactly your `$_GET` variable looks like.

Comment: I would expect a blank page from the first example because you are not printing anything to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first snippet,

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($insert_query))  // What is $mysqli?
```

`$link` is your connection object. Replace `$mysqli` with `$link`.

Comment: That was the noob mistake... :) Thank you!